# Parentheses placement when setting value of object key JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, parentheses

In the past I've solved problems like this problem below where I count the number of times a letter appears in a string by assigning an objects key to its current value or 0 and then adding 1 every time the letter appears again. See the line I refer to below.

```
var letterCount = function(str) {
  noPuncStr = str.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, "")
  // noPuncStr = str.replace(/[^\w]/ig, "") //same thing except underscores would be allowed
  // console.log(noPuncStr);
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < noPuncStr.length; i++) {
    result[noPuncStr[i]] = (result[noPuncStr[i]] || 0) + 1 //THIS LINE. I set the key to its current value if truthy or 0 then add 1
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(letterCount("a%b& c*da"));
```

I just finished a similar sort of problem where I was trying to do the same thing except I wanted to set a key to itself or an empty array if falsely and then to push the current value to the result of the key. However when I did so I got a TypeError: (result[value] || []).push is not a function. Based on looking at other answers to the problem I realized I could've solved it by placing the parentheses at the left end of the line instead of placing it after the = like I did in the letterCount problem above. Why is that the case? To better illustrate what I'm talking about the correct solution and the line I'm referring to is below.

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(fn) {
  var result = {};
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    this.forEach(function(value){
      (result[value] = result[value] || []).push(value); /*WHY is the (
   all the way on the left of the line instead of after the equals sign
   like in letterCount?*/
    })
    return result;
  } else {
    this.forEach(function(value){
      (result[fn(value)] = result[fn(value)] || []).push(value);
    })
    return result;
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** method returns the length of the array:

**Example:**

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(a.push('d'));  //4
```

If you placed the parenthesis like this:

```
result[value] = (result[value] || []).push('Hmm);
```

… then `result[value]` would simply become the length of the array, which is not what you want.

**Example:**

```js
var result = {},
    value = 'v';
    
result[value] = (result[value] || []).push('Hmm');
console.log(result[value]);  //1
```

By placing the parenthesis like this:

```
(result[value] = result[value] || []).push('Success');
```

… `result[value]` is initialized to an empty array *if needed* within the parentheses, and then `Success` is pushed into it.

**Example:**

```js
var result = {},
    value = 'v';
    
(result[value] = result[value] || []).push('Success');
console.log(result[value]);  //Success
```

Comment: I'm still confused why you're right. whoops will edit again and elaborate now.   here: result[value] = (result[value] || []).push('Hmm'); becomes [ ] and [ ].push("hmm") becomes 1. in the next example (result[value] = result[value] || []), result[value] is set to [ ], yet when success is pushed into it, it become Success?  why does [].push('hmm') return 1 while [].push("success") give you ["success"]

Comment: don't worry about responding. figured things out.

Comment: Sorry, had to pick up my wife.  If you still have questions let me know.